# Atomic naming for Atomic classes in java concurrent package

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

We have Atomic classes like AtomicInteger which is used for increment operation. Atomic operation means single operation but increment requires 3 operation. My question is why it is named as AtomicInteger

Comment: I might be wrong. but as far as I know, *atomic* doesn't strictly mean doable in 1 operation (in this case). What it means is that it is a non-interruptible process, and, from the outside, it **can be seen as one operation**.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability

Comment: It's done as a CAS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Atomic" does not necessarily mean that it is a single operation. I like to to think of it as meaning "indivisible," that is, it either entirely happens or it doesn't at all. Even if there are intermediate states where the operation has not completed, from any other class using `AtomicInteger`, an atomic operation will *appear* as either fully completed or not completed at all.